# why addition using += operator is fast as compared to normal addition

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

```
  str=str+(char)(newno+'0')
  str+=newno+'0'
```

statement(1) is showing TLE whereas statement(2) does not.

Comment: Hello, please take the [tour] and read the [help]. As-is it is unclear what you are asking. Welcome to SO.

Comment: What is *TLE* ?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Time limit Exceeded. Online programming challenges expect the submitted program to run in a stipulated time(like `O(nlogn)` instead of a `O(n*n))`

Comment: TLE is time limit exceeded.

Comment: `=` version = 1)Create a string. 2) assign it to `str`. `+=` version = 1)Append to `str`

Comment: @GauravSehgal. Why both the versions are having different time complexity?

Comment: Because assigning a string means `O(length of string)`. Most probably you are doing this in a loop and every time you copy the string.

Comment: We can't say very much about this until you've shown us the *declarations* of `str` and `newno`.  What types are they?

Comment: @TobySpeight str is of type string and newno is of type integer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the additional information (preferably in the form of a [mcve]).  I assume that by "string", you mean a `std::string` and by "integer", an `int`?

Answer (score 1):

The two statements are not at all identical. The first statement creates a new temporary string with `newno+'0'` appended, copies back the new string to `str`, and destroys the temporary object. The second can operate in place, if there is room in `str`.